# How can I run python code with the packages I use without an IDE?

Tags: python

I used PyCharm to write a program that mutes me on discord when I say “mute myself”.
It works fine when I run it with PyCharm, but when I try to run it with idle or cmd, it won't find the modules I use.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may want to look into something like [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org) to manage the [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) for your program. Poetry will help you bundle together the modules your program needs in a structured way.

After you've packaged your program using poetry, check out the ["run" command](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#run).

If you don't like Poetry, you can find other alternatives over on the [PyPA documentation](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm, by default, creates a virtual environment where it installs the modules (the venv folder).

I am assuming you are on windows?
To use that environment's packages you can activate it in your command line

```
venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

and run your script like

```
python main.py
```

Another alternative would be to package your project into a exe using a tool like pyinstaller

```
# while in your virtual environment
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```